# question about integral of e^(-x^2)

Tags: integration

[[image: enter image description here]]

why does dr becomes dr^2? hope someone helps me~!

Comment: $rdr=\frac{1}{2}d(r^2)$

Comment: thank you, positrón0802 ^^

Comment: Alternatively you can set $-r^2=s$ and proceed from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that from the Jacobian matrix, the surface differential $dx\,dy$ transforms to $r\,dr\,d\theta$ in cylindrical coordinates.

Then note from the chain rule that $\frac12 d(r^2)=r\,dr$.

Putting it together yields

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty (\cdot)\,dx\,dy = \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\infty (\cdot)\,r\,dr\,d\theta=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\infty (\cdot)\frac12 d(r^2)\,d\theta$$

Comment: it's embarrassing, but, for the latter part, why is that so?

Comment: The chain rule... and please don't be embarrassed.

Comment: @Dr.MV +1 for kindly explaining. Cheers!

Comment: @qbert Thank you!  Much appreciate the up vote and nice comment.  -Mark

Comment: now it's so obvious, I just couldn't think about using it solving this kind of integral. thank you! but why do you say it's about product rule? i see it d(r^2)/dr=2r.

Comment: Not the product rule;  the chain rule.  So $d(r^2)=2r\,dr$ and hence $\frac12d(r^2)=r\,dr$.

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  -Mark